# Error on connect mail with mailkit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailkit

my code is :

```
Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
client.Authenticate("MyMailAccont@gmail.com", "Password");
....
```

error on Authenticate.eeror is:

> Additional information: POP3 server did not respond with a +OK
>   response to the AUTH command.

my config is well.how to fix it?

Comment: It could be that your gmail account is not enabled for pop3 access.

Comment: I enabled gmail pop3: 1-Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded).2- Enable IMAP

Comment: Your code is working on my Gmail account without any errors. Can you double check the configuration of the authentication. Also you can check your antivirus settings (if you have antivirus program), some of them have integrated Email Shield / Scanner and it may block your requests or the responses. If nothing of the above works please provide more detailed information about the error you are receiving.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

gmail not work very well with pop3.